# CopyFile doesn't work with environmental strings but works only with standard directories where files are placed. Anyway to get past this?

Tags: c++, winapi, file-copying

I want to copy a file using the `CopyFile()` function directly from the WinAPI.

Code works, but the file isn't copied.

Here's the code-

```
CopyFile("%%temp%%\\test.txt", "D:\\Tutorials\\test.txt", FALSE);
```

If I change the `%%temp%%\\test.txt` to something other like `D:\Test\test.txt`, it works but doesn't work for the local profile directory.

Any idea how to get past this?

Comment: Please try to make your titles more informative. Stackoverflow is not a forum. Also, refrain from putting tags in the title. Read [ask].

Comment: "Code works, but the file isn't copied." If both statements are true, how you define "code works"?

Comment: It doesn't work if the directory of the source file is like %%temp%%.
Works only if the source file's directory is standard like D:\test, or C:\Windows.

Comment: Also, that's not the way to get hold of the temporary directory. Use `GetTempPath`. And environment variables are not the way to get hold of the local profile directory either.

Answer (score 6):

Win32 file APIs require paths.  Real paths, not string expressions that evaluate to paths.  They don't perform variable expansion.

If you want variable expansion done on a path, pass it through `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` (and use single `%` before and after the variable name, not doubled) before passing it to `CopyFile`.

Of course, if you are just trying to hardcode access to the temporary directory, not finding strings like `%TEMP%\test.txt` in a configuration file, then you should instead use the OS policy for the temporary directory, available by calling `GetTempPath`.  (Afterwards, use `PathCchCombine` to merge the directory name and file name)

Comment: @blah: Because you didn't do the other thing I said.  "**AND** use single `%`" means you must do both.  Not just pick one and expect success.

Comment: Since the code in question is using the Windows API already, using [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992.aspx) is probably easier. Environment variables are useful for scripting environments, or the command prompt. Regardless of that you did answer the original question: If you want to replace environment variables inside strings with their content, this is how you would do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It depends.  If the path `%TEMP%\test.dat` appears in some user-controlled configuration setting, then expanding it requires `ExpandEnvironmentVariables`.  Using `%TMP%` (via `GetTempPath`) if the user requested `%TEMP%`, or vice-versa, would be wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt My assumption is that the asker is not being deliberate in asking for %TEMP%, just that he is not aware of `GetTempPath`.